# Flutter does not recognise iOS simulator as a device on Mac mini M1

Tags: macos, flutter, visual-studio-code, apple-m1

I used to be able to run my flutter projects in VSCode or Android studio by using the iOS simulator but this time it doesn't let me do it. I does not appear as a flutter device anymore and simply uses chrome to oped it.

flutter devices
1 connected device:

Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google   Chrome 88.0.4324.192

Everything is. perfect when I use flutter doctor. Everything up to date and I re-downloaded Code with the newest version as well.

Can somebody help me find a way of making the iOS simulator one of the flutter devices?

Thanks